# Up key not recognised without modifiers on mac

Tags: mac, keyboard

The up key is not recognised on my Mac (MacOs Sierra 10.12.6, Mac Mini, Generic Logitech K120 105-key keyboard) unless a modifier key is also held down.  It works correctly with any modifier key, just not when there are no modifiers.  The keyboard works fine on my PC, and other keyboards don't work on the Mac, so it definitely doesn't look like a hardware issue.

I've tried opening the keyboard viewer applet, and it doesn't show the key as being pressed when I press it; every other key highlights when I press them.

I've tried disabling the keyboard accessibility options on system preferences, but that doesn't seem to have helped.

Any ideas what might be causing this and how I'd go about fixing it?

Comment: Check with another keyboard. High Sierra is currently 10.13.5 btw, can you check & clarify your question.

Comment: Hmmm... good point.  Thought I'd installed the High Sierra update, but it looks like I'm still on Sierra.

Comment: Same problem persists with another keyboard - in this case a generic oem one.

Comment: OK, test in safe boot & test in another account, to eliminate something you've installed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: somehow, the keyboard shortcut for screen capture had been set to the up arrow.  Noticed what was going on when I turned on sound and started hearing a camera shutter sound...